# Calculate median of a fIle with many columns using awk

Tags: awk

I tried to calculate the median (not the mean) for many columns in a file. I wrote this (an adaptation from a code that works for only 1 column).

```
sort -n <infile | awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i); count[NR] = $i;}END {for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i); if (NR % 2) {print count[(NR + 1) / 2];} else {print (count[(NR / 2)] + count[(NR / 2) + 1]) / 2;}}'
```

Composite cg00000029 cg00000108 cg00000109 cg00000165
TCGA-G4-6298-11A 0.309164840970903   0.108696904309357
TCGA-G4-6311-11A 0.284214936998384   0.192558185484861
TCGA-AA-3506-11A 0.293174399370542   0.12546425658397
TCGA-AA-3713-11A 0.225964654660289   0.150662194530275

Comment: sort -n infile | awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i); count[NR] = $i;}END {for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i); if (NR % 2) {print count[(NR + 1) / 2];} else {print (count[(NR / 2)] + count[(NR / 2) + 1]) / 2;}}'

Comment: Please show how the input data looks and how the expected output data looks. Are there headers, are the data separated by commas, or spaces, or tabs? Do all the lines have the same number of fields? Are some fields blank? Are the numbers integers? Real? Complex? Scientific Notation?

Comment: The infile has headers in the first row and in the first column. It is separated by tabs but I can change it easily by using sed. Columns haven't the same numbers of fields, there is variable (from 0 to all) number of blank fields, and the numbers are real numbers. It looks like this

Comment: Composite cg00000029 cg00000108 cg00000109 cg00000165
TCGA-G4-6298-11A 0.309164840970903   0.108696904309357
TCGA-G4-6311-11A 0.284214936998384   0.192558185484861
TCGA-AA-3506-11A 0.293174399370542   0.12546425658397
TCGA-AA-3713-11A 0.225964654660289   0.150662194530275

Comment: Please do not put code or data in the comments area - it is unformatted and difficult to read. Instead, click `edit` under your question and paste it in there to update it. Thank you.

Comment: To format part of your question as code/data, first select it with the mouse, then click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*.

Comment: Make sure to include both sample input and the expected output given that input in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
$ cat input
Composite cg00000029 cg00000108 cg00000109 cg00000165
TCGA-G4-6298-11A 0.309164840970903 0.108696904309357
TCGA-G4-6311-11A 0.284214936998384 0.192558185484861
TCGA-AA-3506-11A 0.293174399370542 0.12546425658397
TCGA-AA-3713-11A 0.225964654660289 0.150662194530275

$ datamash --header-in -W median 2 < input
0.28869466818446

$ datamash --header-in -W median 3 < input
0.13806322555712
```

See `datamash --help` for the options used above.

Comment: I used exactly the above example and I got  datamash: invalid numeric value in line 2 field 2: '0.309164840970903'

Comment: ok, is my problem. I must set up datamash to use . instead ,!!!

Comment: Exactly. It depends on your locale. Hope this solved your problem.